# Sending Apple Push Notification with 2KB Payload size

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8, apple-push-notifications

According to Apple doc https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html
 it is clear that

> In iOS 8 and later, the maximum size allowed for a notification payload is 2 kilobytes; Apple Push Notification service refuses any notification that exceeds this limit. (Prior to iOS 8 and in OS X, the maximum payload size is 256 bytes)

But from server side we can't send a separate push notification according to iOS type, so i want to send a Push notification with payload size of 2kB(2048 bytes) without failing in iOS 6 & iOS 7 (which are prior to iOS 8). Will it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

When you send the token push to your server, you should send other parameters too like the iOS version, so you can control this kind of things, and for statistics.

I've being doing some tests and you can send 2 kilobytes to iOS 7 devices too, but I've not tested on any iOS 6 device.

Comment: Hi @jcesarmobile, even iOS 8.x devices which are not 64bit are failing to receive Push more than 1 KB. I thing we should consider Bits of device processor rather than iOS version.

Comment: I've tested on iphone 5 with iOS 8 and ipad 4 with iOS 7 (both have 32bits) and both received the same 2KB push notification

Comment: iOS 8 is currently the oldest version supported by the latest tools. I suspect that is why the docs say iOS 8. iOS 7 is end of life